# Navegador abrindo JSON

Tags: php, javascript, html, laravel-4

Tenho um validador que retorna um JSON para um .js que lê esse JSON e exibe as mensagens de erro ou libera o submit. Entretanto, algumas vezes o navegador abre o próprio JSON ao invés de mostrar as mensagens de erro. Alguém já viu algo parecido?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Aparentemente é o comportamento correto, só que você deve acessar esta rota por AJAX e não por GET no navegador.

Comment: Se o seu servidor responde com um JSON e o navegador está abrindo a URL, é natural que ele exiba o JSON. Não entendi qual é o problema aí.

Comment: Anderson, o correto seria o javascript ler esse JSON e adicionar as mensagens de erro ao HTML. Porém, isso ocorre algumas vezes, em outras não.